# Change vim's regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, vim

Is there a way to change vim' regular expressions to python's regular expressions? I'd like to work with python's regular expressions in my vim.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an existing plugin for what you're after, but you can create a plugin for vim which emulates Python's regex. [Here](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2011/09/writing-vim-plugins/) is a guide for writing vim plugins.

Comment: I'll start learning how to built vim plugins. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Vim doesn't support anything except its own Regex engine natively. You must use plugins. The ones that may fit your needs are [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) and [Conque Shell](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771).

These plugins will basically allow you to execute Python code from inside of Vim, so you can work with your Python regex code from inside a Vim buffer.

Comment: I'll try these solutions. Thanks!